# Copy command to Docker container not working as expected

Tags: linux, docker

I have a file on host machine:

> /home/myusername/image.png

And a docker container in which I want to copy a file:

> Container: "my_container"
>
> Location: "/usr/share/app/public/img"

I run command on host machine:

```
sudo docker cp /home/myusername/image.png my_container:/usr/share/app/public/img
```

And I receive an error

> Error response from daemon: mount
> /home/other_user/docker_services/app/other_image.png:/home/docker/overlay2/43432iuaoi3u4acf2ds03830254f89f05cb5d/merged/usr/share/app/public/img/other_image.png,
> flags: 0x500: not a directory

To sum this up: I am trying to copy file "image.png" but getting an error including "other_image.png"

Comment: Anything you `docker cp` into a container will be lost again as soon as the container exits.  Do you mean to `COPY` the file into your image in a Dockerfile, or `docker run -v` to mount host-directory contents into the container when it starts?